# Getting the peak frequency of a note in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, fft

I am trying to get the peak frequency of a musical note by using the FFT function that exists in `MATLAB`. I just copy-pasted the code for FFT of a mathematical function and replaced the function with the audio file.

```
Fs = 44100;                    % Sampling frequency
T = 1/Fs;                     % Sample time
L = 1000;                     % Length of signal
t = (0:L-1)*T;                % Time vector
% Sum of a 50 Hz sinusoid and a 120 Hz sinusoid
y = wavread('c-note2.wav');     
plot(Fs*t(1:50),y(1:50))

xlabel('time (milliseconds)')

NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L); % Next power of 2 from length of y
Y = fft(y,NFFT)/L;
f = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);

% Plot single-sided amplitude spectrum.
plot(f,2*abs(Y(1:NFFT/2+1))) 
title('Single-Sided Amplitude Spectrum of y(t)') 
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('|Y(f)|')
```

Here, instead of `y=wavread('c-note2.wav')`, we had something like `y=0.15sin(5x)+0.32cos(50t)+rand(I)` (To add noise to the signal).

Is what we are trying to do correct? Can we put a wavread instead of a mathematical signal?

From the graph obtained I want to get the peak frequency of the `c-note` and check whether it is matching with the actual frequency of a `c-note`, but I am getting absurd results.

Comment: Have you tried the original code? Did it work? How big is `range(y)`?

Comment: Oh yes, and please explain what exactly "absurd results" are, and why. Have you plotted your `y`? Does it look OK? Having a sound surrounded by a flat line can really change the output of fft.

Comment: The actual frequency of the sound is supposed to be something like 63 Hz, but we are getting something like 5Hz for c note.

Comment: Also, we tried the original code and it gave some plot with some peak frequency, but I have no way of checking if that is correct.
And, we were also getting the same exact value of peak frequency for two totally different notes. I had a data file which sounded like F2 on the keyboard, and when I performed fft, I got a peak at 172.3, which is only one octave off the correct frequency. But when we tried to perform fft of a C note, C3 maybe, we were again getting a peak at 172.3. And we made sure we were not using the same graph by plotting a song for which we got a completely different spectrum.

Answer (score 2):

The pitch of a musical note is very often different from the peak frequency returned by an FFT.  Musical notes usually contain a ton of overtones, many often stronger than the pitch frequency, some possibly even slightly inharmonic in frequency.  Search for pitch detection or estimation algorithms instead of just looking at the FFT spectrum.

Also, when using an FFT to look at the audio spectrum, the length of the FFT has to be longer than several periods of the lowest frequency of interest.  Your FFT length appears to be much too short to resolve 50 Hz (20 mS period).